# How to store 10^6 digit in an integer?

Tags: c++

How to store 10^6 digit in an integer in C++?

I need to save more than 10 power 6 digit in a data type which i can make operations on it. I have tried long long int but of course failed because it is only 64 bit.

Comment: If long long or double double don't help you can use `bignum` library

Comment: If you need 10^6 digits and store the value/do calculations on it with full precision, there is no standard built in C++ integer datatype that will do it for you.

Comment: Do you actually need to have a *precision* of all those digits, or you can keep a shorter mantissa? What operations do you need to perform on those numbers? I cannot imagine an actual problem where you need to work with 10^6 digits, could you explain why you need this? Maybe there are easier solutions...

Comment: I want to check if it's divisible by 7 or not.

Comment: Why do you need to check if a 1000000-digit number is divisible by seven? Where do these numbers come from?

Comment: the problem is storing a 10^6 digit number, not storing it in **an** integer since you can't store anything larger than int size into an int

Comment: I'm learning c++ at my college so I'm trying to solve some problems to increase my knowledge so one problem is to test get a number, shuffle it until i get a number which is divisible by 7.
the range i may get is at least 4 digits and the maximum is 10^6 digits.

Comment: @Kareem Fathy: that's a much easier problem to tackle, which doesn't require any external library nor to implement any storage for those digits. Basically, they are asking you to implement a simplified version of long division. All in all, it's probably 10 lines of code, all you need to do is to track the last remainder and signal when it becomes zero.

Comment: but if he gave me big number the int data type won't store all of it so when I check it I will be checking on another number.

Comment: You can do it without any bignum library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550770/how-to-check-for-division-by-7-for-big-number-in-c

Comment: You must not store the whole number, you can simply work one digit at time, since what matters to you is to check the remainder of each division by seven.

Comment: my problem is to random shuffle it several times until I get the number divisible by 7 
for example if he gave me 12 i print 21. 
so I have to store it in string to shuffle it then I try to pass it to Integer to check if it's divisible by 7 or not and if not i go shuffle again and so on.

Comment: It doesn't change the matter much. Since you are working in decimal anyway (to be able to shuffle the digits efficiently) implementing a division algorithm with a one-digit divisor is trivial, and much more efficient than continuously converting the string to a bigint type.

Comment: @KareemFathy: also, you should update your question adding this additional information about your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

long long can hold up to `9223372036854775807`

Use [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), if you want to perform too much and large numerical operations or store values.

Comment: It's still small number I need 10 power 6 digit I think there is a function to do this but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Get a BigInt library.  GnuMP is a favorite:

- https://gmplib.org/

You can also just write your own class - there are many examples you can adapt.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be an "[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)"; the real question is:

> I'm learning c++ at my college so I'm trying to solve some problems to increase my knowledge so one problem is to test get a number, shuffle it until i get a number which is divisible by 7. the range i may get is at least 4 digits and the maximum is 10^6 digits.
>
> my problem is to random shuffle it several times until I get the number divisible by 7 for example if he gave me 12 i print 21. so I have to store it in string to shuffle it then I try to pass it to Integer to check if it's divisible by 7 or not and if not i go shuffle again and so on.

This problem is way easier; it's basically implementing a decimal long division for one-digit divisors. The naive approach is extremely simple:

```
bool DivisibleBySeven(const char *str)
{
    int remainder=0;
    for(;*str;++str)
        remainder=(remainder*10+(*str-'0')) % 7;
    return remainder==0;
}
```

This can surely be enhanced for performance (e.g. converting larger clusters of digits to perform less divisions), but this is the basic idea - which by the way is how you would perform this with pencil and paper.

Notice that probably in this case working with binary bignum libraries is not going to give you any advantage, since most of the time would be wasted converting from the string representation (that you need to efficiently perform the digits shuffle) and the internal binary representation.

Answer (score 0):

Use or write a big integer library. SO is not the place to ask for or point to any specific library, but if you have selected an option (a specific library or rolling your own) and have specific questions, we’r here to help.

Comment: How to write a big integer library ?  could you give me any link to read about that, please ?

Comment: SO is not really a place to ask for external links, but here you go: http://bit.ly/1d8Wjvg – also note that the “Related” section on the right contains at least two questions that may be relevant.

Comment: @Kareem Fathy: Writing a bigint library with decent performance is not trivial, especially if you need to work with numbers that big. You should probably stick to existing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigIntegerLibrary.h` header file and calculate for very large values.

You can refer this link for the help.
[BigInt Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).