# How to find if the number is a multiple of 7 efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, numbers

There are multiple ways to find out the same and I tried using bitwise operation as -

```
if(((n<<3) - n)%7 == 0 ) {
    print "divide by 7";
}
```

Is there any other more efficient way?

As we can find if number is multiple of 3 using below algorithm -

**If difference between count of odd set bits (Bits set at odd positions) and even set bits is multiple of 3 then so is the number.**

Can we generalize the above algorithm for other numbers too?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262472/integer-division-by-7).

Comment: Division is fast on a modern processor. I doubt you can beat hardware division unless you're programming for the GBA or something.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (X % 7)==0` ?

Comment: In general a number is divisible by `n` if the sum of its digits in base `n+1` is divisible by `n`.  So you can use the octal system in your case (groups of 3 bits) thats why it works.

Comment: You can skip one substraction by using `if(n%7 == 0)`...

Comment: I am considering that i use same hardware for multiple implementation, so which one will be faster?
As using bitwise is always faster, so modulo is going to be slower than bitwise operator.

Comment: @CodeQuestor It is not obvious that bitwise is faster.  A hardware divide or modulo happens in the cpu, without reading additional instructions. doing loops, summing in some temporary register, etc.

Comment: I'm puzzled.  Your code `if ((n << 3) - n) % 7 == 0)` is equivalent to `if ((7 * n) % 7 == 0)`, which is trivially true for all values of `n`.  Who's confused — me or you?  My compiler agrees with me; maybe I've brainwashed it to my way of thinking?

Comment: "As using bitwise is always faster" Are you sure that's true? Have you compared the performance for your algorithm for testing if numbers are divisible by 3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for division by 7 for big number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550770/how-to-check-for-division-by-7-for-big-number-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if your number is representable by a hardware-supported integer, and the hardware has a division or modulo operations, you should just use those. It is simpler, and probably faster than anything you will write.  To even compete with the hardware, you must use an assembler and use other faster instructions better than the hardware manufacturers did, and without the advantage of undocumented tricks they could use but you can not.

Where this question becomes interesting is where arbitrarily large integers are involved.  Modulo has some tricks for that.  For instance, I can tell you that 100000000010000010000 is divisible by 3, even though my brain is a horribly slow math processor compared to a computer, because of these properties of the `%` modulo operator:

- `(a+b+c) % d = ( (a%d) + (b%d) + (c%d) ) %d`
- `(n*a) % d = ( (a%d) + (a%d) + (a%d) +... (n times) ) %d = (n*(a%d)) %d`

Now note that:

- 10 % 3 = 1
- 100 % 3 = (10 * (10%3)) % 3 = 10%3 = 1
- 1000 % 3 = (10 * (100%3)) %3 = 1
  etc...

So that to tell if a base-10 number is divisible by 3, we simply sum the digits and see if the sum is divisible by 3

Now using the same trick with a large binary number expressed in octal or base-8 (also pointed out by @hropyatr above in comments), and using divisibility by 7, we have the special case:

`8 % 7 = 1`

and from that we can deduce that:

`(8**N) % 7 = (8 * (8 * ( ... *( 8 * (8%7) % 7 ) % 7 ) ... %7 = 1`

so that to "quickly" test divisibility by 7 of an arbitrarily large octal number, all we need to do is add up its octal base-8 digits and try dividing that by 7.

Finally, the bad news.

The code posted:

`if ( (n<<3 - n) % 7 ==0 ) ...` is not a good test for divisibility by 7.

because it is always yields `true` for any `n` (as pointed out by @Johnathan Leffler)

n<<3 is multiplication by 8, and will equal `8n`

So for instance 6 is not divisible by 7,

but `6<<3 = 48` and `48 - 6 = 42`, which is divisible by `7`.

If you meant right shift `if ( (n>>3 - n ) % 7 == 0 )` that doesn't work either.  Test it with 49, `49//8` is `6`, `6-49` is `-43` and although 49 is divisible by 7, `-43` is not.

The simplest test, `if (n % 7 ) == 0` is your best shot until n overflows hardware, and at that point you can find a routine to represent n in octal, and sum the octal digits modulo 7.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation Paul.

Answer (score 2):

I think `if(n%7 == 0)` is more efficient way to check divisibility by 7.
But if you are dealing with large numbers and can't directly do `modulus` operation then this might help:

1. A number of the form `10x + y` is divisible by `7` if and only if `x − 2y` is divisible by `7`. In other words, subtract twice the last digit from the number formed by the remaining digits. Continue to do this until a number known to be divisible by `7` is obtained. The original number is divisible by `7` if and only if the number obtained using this procedure is divisible by `7`.
   For example, the number `371: 37 − (2×1) = 37 − 2 = 35; 3 − (2 × 5) = 3 − 10 = −7;` thus, since `−7`is divisible by `7`, `371` is divisible by `7`.
2. Another method is multiplication by `3`. A number of the form `10x + y` has the same remainder when divided by `7` as `3x + y`. One must multiply the leftmost digit of the original number by `3`, add the next digit, take the remainder when divided by `7`, and continue from the beginning: multiply by `3`, add the next digit, etc.
   For example, the number `371: 3×3 + 7 = 16` remainder `2`, and `2×3 + 1 = 7`.
   This method can be used to find the remainder of division by 7.
   P.S: [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_7)

Comment: Thanks Milan for discussing the question.