# How to check if a big decimal number can be divided by 2^x or 5^x

Tags: algorithm, division, modulus

I have a big decimal number `N` (up to `100.000` digits) and I need to check if `N` can be divided by `2^X` or `5^X ( 0 < X < 5 )`.

```
bignumber % (2^x) == 0
```

Can I get a tip? I don't have any idea.

Comment: Have you looked up how to check if one number is a multiple of the other? Resources exist for that everywhere. Also, please don't tag multiple languages.

Comment: What is the representation of the big number? If you are using a bignum library, then division with remainder should already be one of the basic operations.

Comment: for 5^x there is no bitwise-test

Comment: What form is this number? All you really want to do is divide with remainder and if you can do it x times with no remainder. Bingo.
If it's binary that amounts to  the lowest x bits are zero for 2^x.

Comment: for each digit compute its value mod n (its value in that number, not just digit itself), this is periodic so should not require big number operations. Then sum the values mod n where the bits are set. If its 0 then n divides the number. This can be applied to any base with little modifications.

Comment: I have a strong hunch that the number is actually a decimal string

Comment: In C and C++, the `^` symbol denotes an XOR operation. Can you please post some *actual code* representing your problem? The method you are using to store your "big number" is very important here. Is it a binary integer? Is it a string of ASCII decimal digits? Or is it something else?

Comment: If it is a decimal string consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1550786/8051589).

Comment: Don't spam tags. C and C++ are different languages. Pick **one**.

Comment: This is a mathematics problem, not C or C++.

Comment: @AndreKampling divisibility of decimal numbers by 7 and by 2 are very different things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the number consisting of the last x digits. If it can be divided by 2^x, all number can, too. The same about 5^x.

The reason is that a decimal number with x last zeroes can always be divided by 2^x or 5^x, because it can be divided by 10^x. So, we can forget about the start digits and check only the last x ones.

For checking the divisibility use

```
char* number; // here the source number is put

strcopy(ending, &number[strlen(number) - x]);
long CheckedNumber = atoi(ending);

long NewCheckedNumber;
int i=0;
while (i<x){
  NewCheckedNumber = CheckedNumber / 5;
  if ( NewCheckedNumber * 5 != CheckedNumber ) return 0;
  CheckedNumber = NewCheckedNumber;
  i++;
}
return 1;
```

Comment: To explain notice 10^y for y>x is always divisible by 2^x and 5^x. So you only need consider the remainder for the low x digits (if it's in a decimal form).

Comment: @Persixty You are right. If so easy question appears, I need to explain.

Comment: A further tip is that dividing by 5 amounts to dividing by 10 and doubling. So if the last digit isn't 0 or 5 then fail. knock off the last digit and double the result (which is super easy) and if you knocked off a 5 add one. If that doesn't end in a 5 or a zero, fail. Do that x times and you're done.

Comment: @Persixty yes, for c/c++ it will work so. Maybe. For I don't know is the comparison in the standard function made from the end or from the start. And at any rate, the questioner obvoiusly needs the maximally easy explanation.

Comment: I'm thinking my prescription is easier than implementing a full blown division algorithm unless x is sufficiently constrained that sufficient digits will go into an integer type.

Comment: Only up to last 5 digits have to be checked. They easily can fit into long.

Comment: Missed that rule. Probably invented to give the out. Though makes it a bit boring because sure the entertainment is then calculating an asymptotically linear rule!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148332/discussion-between-gangnus-and-persixty).

Answer (score 0):

If `0 < x < 5` => Very easy :)

`X` is an integer, definitively. => `X = 1,2,3,4`

You just check for each case.
For example `X = 4  => 5^4 = 625`

You must check whether Bignumber % 625 == 0

You known that `10000 % 625 == 0` 
=> Just check the last `4` if these `4` number is divided by `625` => the big number is divided by `625`.

OK for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are faced with 2 issues:

1. How to store a large number.
2. How to compute a division on that number and get the remainder.

Storing such a large number on a computer is a challenge.  But any number can be represented as a polynomial.

```
ex: 10235
base 10 -->  10235 = f(10) = 1x10^5 + 0x10^4 + 2x10^3 + 3x10^2 + 3x10 + 5
base 16 --> 0x37FB = g(16) = 2x16^3 + 7x16^2 + 15x16^1 + 11
```

Using this concept, one can readily use polynomial addition, subtraction, multiplication and division to compute very large values with no accuracy loss.  The polynomial's coefficients only need to be set so they are all of the same sign when printing the number.

To print a number store in base N to base 10, one has to compute f so f(10) = g(N).

This concept can be optimized with numbers larger than 10, to reduce computation time, but you need to keep in mind that a 31-bits x 32-bits (multiplication takes 64.  Negative coefficients or coefficients larger than your base can be reduced using the same carry/borrow techniques we routinely use when doing arithmetic operations by hand.

You can develop your own polynomials library, and deal with the loops and the maths, or use an open-source library, like GMP.

Some info on polynomial division remainder:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem

I'd go with using GMP.

Comment: You don't really need to store long number, you need only up to last 5 digits.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.mathsisfun.com/divisibility-rules.html

There should be listed when a number is divisible or not. It's for all numbers, no matter how large.

Comment: link only answers are discouraged, because external resources can change or become unavailable. You need to add the relevant quotes/summaries. That being said, in this particular case I don't see how that link is useful at all. It covers very basic divisibility rules. The OP has some specific requirements which requires more advanced math.